# I got Not enough data available error with Carbon createFromFormat method

Tags: php-carbon

I try to parse with carbon datetime value in sstring as "2020-09-17T14:08:59Z", but with format :

```
Carbon::createFromFormat($stringData,'Y-m-d H:i:s' )
```

I got error :

```
Not enough data available to satisfy format {"exception":"[object] (Carbon\\Exceptions\\InvalidFormatException(code: 0): The format separator does not match
```

Which format have I to use ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong parameters order, and wrong format (`\T` instead of space to match your separator, and `e` to get the timezone)

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:se', $stringData)
```

Or you can simply let Carbon find out the format:

```
Carbon::parse($stringData)
```

Comment: Thank you! But I got "Unexpected data found." error. Which format have I to use ?

Comment: I see, your format contains a space and no timezone, your $stringData contain "T" where your format has space and it has a timezone (Z). But your format is standard, so I'd recommend you simply `Carbon::parse($stringData)` and just let `Carbon` (`DateTime`) find out the format.